# Doctrine ORM Pagination count of returned results

Tags: doctrine-orm, pagination, doctrine

Have got Doctrine pagination working perfectly, but one of the requirements is at the bottom of the table of results to show `Displaying X of X results`.

Getting the total results is not a problem as you can simply do:

```
$paginator = new Paginator($query);
echo $paginator->count(); // total results for the query
```

I can get a count of the currently displayed results using:

```
$paginator = new Paginator($query);
echo $paginator->getIterator()->count();
```

But this results in 2 additional queries being executed, I'd love a way to get this count with only 3 queries instead of 5!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I have found has been to extend the doctrine paginator as followed which works but I feel theres a better solution?

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as DoctrinePaginator;

class Paginator extends DoctrinePaginator
{
    protected $iterator;

    public function getIterator()
    {
        if (is_null($this->iterator)) {
            $this->iterator = parent::getIterator();
        }

        return $this->iterator;
    }
}
```